# Srcset Property selects wrong images

Tags: html, css

The srcset property loads the 1600px Image on my Samsung Galaxy S6 and potentially on any other mobile device, and I dont really understand why.

```
        <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/hypestyle/image/upload/c_scale/cx5lqdelvrpwbytwgm5d.jpg"
     srcset="https://res.cloudinary.com/hypestyle/image/upload/c_scale,w_200/cx5lqdelvrpwbytwgm5d.jpg 200w,
    https://res.cloudinary.com/hypestyle/image/upload/c_scale,w_400/cx5lqdelvrpwbytwgm5d.jpg 400w,
    https://res.cloudinary.com/hypestyle/image/upload/c_scale,w_800/cx5lqdelvrpwbytwgm5d.jpg 800w,
    https://res.cloudinary.com/hypestyle/image/upload/c_scale,w_1200/cx5lqdelvrpwbytwgm5d.jpg 1200w,
    https://res.cloudinary.com/hypestyle/image/upload/c_scale,w_1600/cx5lqdelvrpwbytwgm5d.jpg 1600w" 
sizes=" (min-width: 100px) 100vw,
        (min-width: 768px) 100vw,
        (min-width: 992px) 50vw,
        (min-width: 1200px) 30vw" class="postFeedImage">
```

Comment: pixel-density perhaps?

Comment: A first step is to clear the browser's cache.

Comment: @AndyG I know I did that :/

Comment: I would take a step back and simplify it; test it just switching between two images. (This is a debugging comment.)